# How do you add scroll bars to a (Bar) chart in Qlikview

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I have a bar chart in QlikView and its summarising the data that isnt in the top 10 as `OTHER` which needs to be clicked to bring the next 10.

I want to add a scroll bar to this so it shows all data and can be scrolled through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to disable Dimension Limits? Sounds like you have checked "Show only largest 10 values" with "Show others".

In the `Dimension Limits` tab untick `Restrict which values are displayed using the first expression`

Then in the `Presentation` tab tick `Enable X-Axis Scrollbar`

Comment: Yeh i managed to get this by doing the above and also Enabling X Axis Scrolling in the presentation tab

Comment: In the Dimension Limits tab untick Restrict which values are displayed using the first expression

Then in the Presentation tab tick Enable X-Axis Scrollbar